# Django crispy forms always renders readonly

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using `django-cripy-forms` and I want to make a field be readonly or not, depending on other things that happen in my code. My current code for a form looks like:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Submit
from django import forms
from .models import Contact


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        exclude = ['author']

    contact_email = forms.EmailField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), required=True)

    def __init__(self, email_readonly=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'contact-form'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('contact_email', readonly=email_readonly),
            Field('content'),
            Submit('', 'Send')
        )
```

But this always renders the `contact email` field as readonly.

---

In fact, I noticed that the only way that the field is not readonly is if the key `readonly` doesn't even appear in the `Field` constructor, i.e.

```
Field('contact_email', readonly=False),
```

has the exact same effect as

```
Field('contact_email', readonly=True),
```

while I would expect it to have the same effect as

```
Field('contact_email'),
```

Is this a bug or am I misusing the code?

---

**Edit**:

In my template, I have both the line

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

and

```
{% crispy form %}
```

I am rendering the template with

```
render(request, 'main_site/contact.html', context={'form':ContactForm(email_readonly=False)})`
```

or

```
render(request, 'main_site/contact.html', context={'form':ContactForm(email_readonly=True)})`
```

with `True` and `False` being set somewhere else (I don't think that's relevant for the current question, as the current question only refers to the strange behaviour when `email_readonly` is set to `False`)

Comment: How are you using `ContactForm` in the view?

Comment: @Alasdair The standard way of rendering a template containing the line `{% crispy form %}` with `render(request, 'main_site/contact.html', context={'form': ContactForm(email_readonly=False)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Crispy Forms - see [#326](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/326), and [#257](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/257) which is the root of the issue.

The `readonly` attribute is a boolean attribute as opposed to a key-value attribute, i.e., you can use it like this:

```
<input name='foo' readonly>
```

The presence of the attribute means that the field is readonly.

Crispy forms does not handle such boolean attributes (with the exception of the [`required` attribute](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#bootstrap-helper-attributes) which is has a special case for) and just renders them as it would any other attribute.

This is a problem because as far as your browser is concerned, `readonly="true"` and `readonly="false"` are the same thing. The mere presence of that attribute will cause the field to be read-only.

You could do something like this as a workaround:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('contact_email', readonly=True) if email_readonly else Field('contact_email'),
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did for a temporary workaround. I guess it's now permanent :D